# Uncaught TypeError: treelist.autoFitCloumn is not a function in kendo treelist

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I am using Kendo treelist and in that autofitColumn function. But it is throwing error that, Autofitcolumn is not a function.

Can anyone tell,what is the problem??

My code:

```
$('#treelist').kendoTreeList({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    editable: false,
    columns: [
        { field: "FileType", title: "Files" },
        { field: "DestDrive", title: "Drives", template: "<select id= \"drivedropdown\" class=\"form-control\"  # for (var i = -1, len=DestDrive.length;i<len ; i++) {# <option> #=DestDrive[i]# </option> #}# /> " },
        { field: "DestPath", title: "Path", template: "<input id=\"pathtextbox\" class=\"form-control input-sm \" />" }
    ],
    scrollable: true,
    //resizable: true,
    messages: {
        loading: "Fetching DB details...",
    }
})var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");  treeList.autoFitColumn(0);
```

Comment: Yes, maybe someone can tell you what's the problem, but only when you share your code. We haven't got a crystal ball.

Comment: It seems that the kendo-tree is not full initialised when you request the `autoFitColumn()` method. If you put a `setTimeout()` it works?

Comment: No, its not working...

Comment: Well, you need to provide us a working example, using stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net, reproducing the issue you have. When you share us a working example with the error we can help you better. I will stay in tune with this post waiting for more info.

Comment: Demo:  http://dojo.telerik.com/UZAhE/17     Here, autoFitColumn is not working.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/autosize-treelist-columns The same problem than yours with a solution.

Comment: I followed the same document but still not working..

Answer (score 0):

You are using Kendo 2015.1.408.

autoFitColumn() seems to have been added in 2015.2.805.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/OxUNa

Comment: I tried in kendo 2016.2.607... In this also autoFitColumn() is not working

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then.  Your exact dojo code does work in 2016.2.607 (http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AVOKe).  So if the dojo does not work for you then there is something very strange going on OR your actual code is not correct/not including the correct version of kendo.